# Extra argument python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

So im try to crop an image with PIL but it says i am using 5 arguments.

```
im.crop((im_x / total_x_frames) * frame, 0 ,(im_x / total_x_frames) * (frame + 1), im_y / total_y_frames)
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Python always passes the object on which you are calling the method as the first argument, so the first argument here is `im`.

Comment: So since its a crop function what would i put inside the brackets?

Comment: PIL.image.crop receives one argument - a tuple of four. Do this `im.crop( ((im_x / total_x_frames) * frame, 0 ,(im_x / total_x_frames) * (frame + 1), im_y / total_y_frames) )`

Answer (score 2):

From the [Pillow docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=crop#PIL.Image.Image.crop) it looks like the crop method takes a tuple with 4 values for the coordinates. Parentheses suggested by Brian should work because it will make your argument a single tuple.

```
im.crop(((im_x / total_x_frames) * frame, 0 ,(im_x / total_x_frames) * (frame + 1), im_y / total_y_frames))
```

Answer (score 0):

try extra parenthesis `im.crop( ((im_x / total_x_frames) * frame, 0 ,(im_x / total_x_frames) * (frame + 1), im_y / total_y_frames))`